# How to replace WooCommerce My Account registration form with a Gravity User Registration Form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, gravity-forms-plugin, user-registration

I would appreciate it if anyone could advise how to replace WooCommerce `My Account` registration form with a form created by the `Gravity Forms User Registration` plugin.

Thank you,

I tried the `Enable Custom Registration Page` option, but it changed only the WordPress default registration form, not the `WooCommerce`'s.